# Get current sentence by cursor/caret position

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string containing multiple sentences.  I also have the current cursor/caret position.

I need to be able to extract the current sentence at the given cursor position.

For example, take this string:

`This is the first sentence.  And this is the second! Finally, this is the third sentence`

If the current cursor position is `33` then the cursor is in the second sentence.

In which case, the result returned should be:

`And this is the second!`

I only need to use the standard sentence definers of `.?!`

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Although I am expecting regex to be required, if there is a faster alternative using native methods I would be interested in that also.

Comment: Just split by `.?!` and add the lengths until you get a length >= current position.

Comment: Try [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qqzssoyv/) - is it what you are looking for?

Comment: @stribizhev Perfect... And I also feel a bit dumb for not realizing how simple the solution was in the first place.  Regardless, if you would like to write it up into an answer, I will award it to you.

Comment: Since it works, I posted the suggestion. Glad to help. Actually, you already had a regex  ready, just a bit of logics were missing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve what you need: use `String#split` with `/[?!.]/g` to get an array of sentences and then iterate over the array to sum up the lengths of the sentences found, and if the index is smaller than the count, return the sentence.

```js
function getSentenceByPos(idx, str) {
    pos = 0;
    array = str.split(/[?!.]/g);
    for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
   pos += array[i].length + 1;
        if (pos >= idx) {
            return array[i];
        }
 }
}// 26 still 1 then `.`. 51 then `!` - 53 is 3rd sentence!
document.write(getSentenceByPos(53, "This is the first sentence.  And this is the second! Finally, this is the third sentence"));
```

Comment: But you are removing the delimiters from the phrase when making the split.. Will this work with a cursor just over one delimiter?

Comment: @Amarnasan: I get your point. So, in fact, the `pos` should be incremented when iterating. `pos += array[i].length + 1;` fixes it.

Comment: -1 for using `for..in` on an array. **[`for...in` does not guarantee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in) the order in which the elements are iterated over**. This code relies on it iterating in order.

Comment: @UselessCode: Is `for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++)` better?

Comment: Much better. Your original code is not guaranteed to always produce the correct answer! It is a fairly serious and hard to debug flaw that many people (especially novices) would struggle with. Many people who come to SO for help will copy your answer verbatim even if  they don't understand it and will copy that flaw with it.

Comment: @UselessCode: Thank you for letting know.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add an answer that doesn't use regular expression to split up the
string because doing so is quite inefficient and would likely be very slow on
larger chunks of text.

The most efficient way to do it would probably be to use a couple of loops to search, requiring only 2 passes to find the ends of the sentence.

```
var sentenceFromPos = function (s, pos) {
  var len = s.length,
    start,
    end,
    char;

  start = pos;
  end = pos;

  while (start >= 0) {
    char = s.charAt(start);
    if (char === '.' || char === '?' || char === '!') {
      break;
    }
    start -= 1;
  }

  while (end < len) {
    char = s.charAt(end);
    if (char === '.' || char === '?' || char === '!') {
      break;
    }
    end += 1;
  }

  return s.substring(start + 1, end + 1).trim();
};

var phrase = 'This is the first sentence.  And this is the second! Finally, this is the third sentence';

console.log(sentenceFromPos(phrase, 10));
console.log(sentenceFromPos(phrase, 33));
console.log(sentenceFromPos(phrase, 53));
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will respect cursors over the limits of the phrases (like `!` or `.`)

```
function getPhrase(string, cursor) {
    phrases = string.match(/.*?(!|\.|$)/g)
    basecursor = 0;
    phrase = phrases[0]
    for(ii=0; ii<phrases.length-1; ii++) {
        if (basecursor+phrases[ii].length<cursor) {
            phrase = phrases[ii+1]
            basecursor += phrases[ii].length
        }
    }
    return(phrase)
}
string = "This is the first sentence.  And this is the second! Finally, this is the third sentence"
cursor = 0
phrase = getPhrase(string, cursor)
document.write(phrase)
```

Comment: FYI: `.*?(!|\.|$)` does not support `?` as a sentence end. Then, splitting against `[?!.]` is quicker than lazy dot matching. Also, `.*?` will not match a newline (that might not be relevant here). And just another pet peeve: when you use alternations there is more backtracking than without, although with your approach, you have to use an alternation. Otherwise, a nice alternative.